# React-testing-library button click replacing dom elements rather than replicating them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a simple application that calls an API and adds an image to the DOM on click:

```js
export const DogGallery = () => {
  const [dogPhotos, setDogPhotos] = useState([]);
  const getDogPhoto = async () => {
    const newPhoto = await fetch(
      "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random"
    ).then((res) => res.json());
    const photosArray = [...dogPhotos, newPhoto.message];
    setDogPhotos(photosArray);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <p>Dog gallery</p>
      <Button handleClick={getDogPhoto} />
      {dogPhotos.length > 0 &&
        dogPhotos.map((photo, i) => (
          <DogPhoto source={photo} key={i} number={i} />
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

However, when I test this in react-testing-library and fire the click even five times, I still end up with one image in the DOM.

```js
const clickButton = () => {
  const buttonElement = screen.getByText("click!");
  fireEvent.click(buttonElement);
};

it("should render 5 images", async () => {
  render(<DogGallery />);
  clickButton();
  clickButton();
  clickButton();
  clickButton();
  clickButton();
  const elements = await screen.findAllByRole("image");
  expect(elements.length).toBe(5); // fails, as it only returns a length of 1
});
```

How can I get react-testing-library to replicate/add images to the dom rather than replacing them?

I perform tests for 0 images and 1 image and they both pass.

You can see the full code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bash-cwttx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the problem is with your `ClickElement()` function.

What if they are not selecting the proper element.

Two ways to debug is to `console.log(buttonElement)` or just use a different selector, e.g. CSS ID:

```
const clickButton = () => {
  const buttonElement = screen.getById("YOUR_BUTTON_ID");
  fireEvent.click(buttonElement);
};
```

<sup>Untested</sup>

Comment: Edited to include the click button fn. I can get the button alright, because the 1 image test works. It seems like each time the click event is fired, it replaces the dom element rather than adding to it.